# how to send input values from host computer to arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, firmware

how to send input values from host computer to arduino,such that speficing the number of rotations for a stepper motor etc

Comment: Via serial. Most CNCs and 3D printers send GCode over serial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method is to use the serial communication. Use the sample code at http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SwitchCase2, upload that to an Arduino, start the serial monitor (Ctrl+Shift+M), make sure the baud rate is the same as set in the code (9600 in this case), then write the commands and send them to the Arduino.

**Edit**
Since the serial characters are usually read one by one you need a character that will signal the end of the string. This is usually a newline `\n`, but can be any character you choose (and can be sent to Arduino).

Sample code (`processString` would be your function to do something with the string):

```
char buf[64];
byte cnt = 0;
void loop() 
{
    while (Serial.available()>0) {
        byte c = Serial.read();
        // Check for terminator character or the size of buffer
        if (c == '\n' || cnt >= 63) {
            // Add the terminating 0
            buf[cnt] = 0;
            // Process the full string
            processString(buf);
            // Prepare to read the next string
            cnt = 0;
        } else {
            // Not terminator - add to string
            buf[cnt++] = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay.If i want to sent a string the same read() is used? Is there any modifications needed for sending strings?

Comment: check my updated answer above